# Update the data of linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

Is it possible to update a LinkedList node's data? If yes then how? I actually need a hint!

Answer (score 3):

Two options here, depending upon whether you're storing mutable types or not:

1. if you're storing mutable types (frex simple Beans with getters/setter methods), you could simply update the state of the object (nothing to do with the LinkedList implementation itself)
2. if you're storing immutable types (frex Strings), you could override the previous element at the position in the linked list with a new instance by using [LinkedList.set()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#set%28int,%20E%29)

If you're storing a custom type, then it's really design issue (whether you want to make that type mutable or not).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. Use [`LinkedList.set(pos, newValue)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#set%28int,%20E%29).

Comment: but can i do it manually? if yes than how? give me a hint.thanks

Comment: +1 if you need to use this, you should consider an ArrayList.

Comment: @JunaidHassan What do you mean by manually?

Comment: I mean not with the Java built in Methods or Classes I want to know about the algorithm or the technique to access the old node and then update it with new data thanks

Comment: Read about encapsulation. If LinkedList let you access to the nodes it used internally, you could break its invariants by, for example, adding a node without incrementing the list size, or by making the list circular. The Linked List offers all the methods you might need to modify the list without any need to access its internal, private fields. That's a fundamental principle of object oriented design.

Comment: You can do this by adding AtomicReference to all the nodes in the list.  You can change the AtomicReference any time.  You shouldn't need to do this.  Just use the List as it was designed to be used.

Comment: I just want to know about how to update the linked list nodes data ! i don't want to break or change any class. I just want to know how can I do it manually like
for(Node n=first; n!=null; n++){
if(n.data==key){

//here i want to know how to update the old data
}
}

Comment: Use the indexOf() method to find the index of first node containing the data you want to replace, and use the set() method to store another object in this node. And read the javadoc of LinkedList. All the methods are described there, and you can't use any other way to modify the list.

Comment: There is no advantage in accessing the nodes directly and there is every reason not to do this. If you are worried about performance, ArrayList may be a better choice for this operation.

Answer (score 0):

> but can i do it manually? if yes than how?

If by "do it manually" you mean by breaking the `LinkedList` classes encapsulation and directly updating the classes private data structures ...

- It is possible to do this using reflection.
- It is a really bad idea / bad practice to try.

The right way to do this is to use the `set` operation.  If you are worried by the cost of iterating the linked list to do this, use a different `List` implementation.  The `set` operation is fast on an `ArrayList`, or you could maybe do this with a custom linked list implementation.

Comment: the what will be good idea?

Comment: A good idea is to use the public interface offered by LinkedList. If you want to replace an object by a new one at a specific indes, use the `set()` method, as indicated by the other answers.